# How to split a context in two

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm new to ReactJS and I come from a back-end (
Ruby on Rails) background. This is my first ReactApp

Read the docs and seems like my [LocationContextProvider](https://github.com/MatayoshiMariano/feeltheworld/blob/stackoverflow-question/src/contexts/LocationContext.js) is kinda big. My goal here is that in every [place](https://github.com/MatayoshiMariano/feeltheworld/blob/stackoverflow-question/src/contexts/LocationContext.js#L16) change I would like to:

1. Change the Spotify Playlist being played, that can be done by changing the playlist ID
2. Change a Video Component (not created yet) where I can show a text like "Japan, Chiyoda @ Night" in the sidebar. That string is saved in [videoPlaying](https://github.com/MatayoshiMariano/feeltheworld/blob/stackoverflow-question/src/contexts/LocationContext.js#L19) and changed every time a video change. That happens when a video ends (I check if the location selected has another video to show, that's done [here](https://github.com/MatayoshiMariano/feeltheworld/blob/stackoverflow-question/src/contexts/LocationContext.js#L61)) or the user selects a new location.

What I want to achieve is to separate the LocationContext's state into different Context:

```js
    this.state = {
      player: undefined,
      country: randomPlace.country,
      city: randomPlace.city,
      place: randomPlace.place, // This is street or the actual place
      videosPlayed: [], // Here we will push all the youtubeIDs played, we will empty it when the location is changed
      videosAllowedToPlay: videosAllowedToPlay,
      videoPlaying: undefined,
      setCountry: this.setCountry,
      setCity: this.setCity,
      setPlace: this.setPlace,
      setVideoPlaying: this.setVideoPlaying
    };
```

For example having two new contexts:

Context 1:

```js
    this.state = {
      player: undefined,
      country: randomPlace.country,
      city: randomPlace.city,
      place: randomPlace.place, // This is street or the actual place
      videosPlayed: [], // Here we will push all the youtubeIDs played, we will empty it when the location is changed
      videosAllowedToPlay: videosAllowedToPlay,
      setCountry: this.setCountry,
      setCity: this.setCity,
      setPlace: this.setPlace,
    };
```

Context 2:

```js
    this.state = {
      videoPlaying: undefined,
      setVideoPlaying: this.setVideoPlaying
    };
```

So that based on the state of Context1 I can change Context2's `videoPlaying` property (Not sure how or where to do that)

And then consume Context2 instead of consuming LocationContext and re-rendering the entire component every time a state's property change, bc I'm really interested only in the videoPlaying property, but I need to save the state of the Context1's properties.

Thanks in advance!

Source Code: https://github.com/MatayoshiMariano/feeltheworld/tree/stackoverflow-question

Comment: This seems a bit broad/opinionated, given that you just link to code and vaguely indicate that you want to split it. Questions will ideally be self-contained and ask specific, answerable Qs.

Comment: @underscore_d I get your point, since and u may be right, I just edited my question, did I make it more clear/less vague?